# using variable inside of env in React

Tags: reactjs, environment-variables, create-react-app

I have an env file with such format:

```
REACT_APP_API_URL_API_LOGIN =  "http://x.x.x.x:1000/api/loginuser"
REACT_APP_API_URL_API_SIGNUP= "http://x.x.x.x:1000/reg/CheckRegister"
REACT_APP_API_URL_API_FETCH_IMAGE = "http://x.x.x.x:1000/api/userImage"
REACT_APP_API_URL_API_VERIFY_USER = "http://x.x.x.x:1000/reg/RegisterUser"
```

as you know for privacy reasons I changed `IP:PORT`

I want to separate my base url, the `x.x.x.x:1000` part. because sometimes I need to change it for testing purposes.

I wish to have such thing:

```
REACT_APP_API_URL_API_BASE = x.x.x.x:1000
REACT_APP_API_URL_API_LOGIN =  "http://REACT_APP_API_URL_API_BASE/api/loginuser"
```

I thought about having 2 different `.env` files or defining a constant inside of React but it will make, editing codes harder. since I must search for my all,fetching functions all the time.

how can I use my base url inside of the same `.evn` file.

Comment: You usually store host name and endpoint path separately

Comment: @Konrad that means there's no way except creating another `.env` file isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

in react .env file, you can use it like this

```
REACT_APP_API_URL_API_BASE = x.x.x.x:1000 
REACT_APP_API_URL_API_LOGIN =  http://$REACT_APP_API_URL_API_BASE/api/loginuser
```

Comment: it gives me CORS error

Comment: that you need to enable from the backend

Comment: how can I do this? actually I only do front end but backend works with .Net Core.

Comment: backend needs to allow your host `x.x.x.x:1000` to access their services. This needs to handle from the .net side

Comment: oh, you mean CORS problem. we don't have this problem. cross origin error only happens when I use this snippet. by manually typing it is working.